# Laravel 5: METHOD-NOT-ALLOWED error

Tags: laravel

I have routes setup as

```
// ----------------------- USER ROUTES -----------------------
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1/user', 'middleware' => 'throttle:5'], function(){    
    Route::post('login', 'UserController@login');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1/user', 'middleware' => 'throttle'], function(){  
    Route::post('checkuser', 'UserController@checkuser');
    Route::post('checkmail', 'UserController@checkmail');
});
```

HTML as

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
```

And I am getting Method not found error

I know somewhere route is not correct, but how to correct it?

Comment: Please, show all your routes file. Do you get the error when submitting the form or when viewing it?

Comment: Entire route file can not share as space is limited ... though I get this error when I try to view login page

Comment: After I updated the routes to  

`**Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1/user', 'middleware' => 'throttle: 5'], function()  
{  
    Route::get('login', 'UserController@login'); // Added this line  
    Route::post('login', 'UserController@login');  
});**`  
  
I get following error:    
*A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.*

Comment: It seems to be in a redirect loop. Do you have your `Route::group` within another group? If you are in `5.2` this group also needs to adhere to the new `web` middleware introduced in `5.2`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it should be `{{ url('v1/user/login') }}`.

To avoid using `url()` you can leverage named routes.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes